# Shiny Display Matrix as Table from UI

Tags: html, r, shiny

I would like to display a matrix as a table without having to make a server call. I suspect I need something like the following

### ui.r

```
x <- diag(4)

h4(x), ## fails
h4(xtable(x)), ## fails
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if that is easily possible. As far as I know, you would have to create the right HTML for the table to display, for example using the [`htmlTable` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/htmlTable/vignettes/tables.html).

An example is given below, hope this helps!

```
library(shiny)
library(htmlTable)

df = data.frame(a=LETTERS[1:6],b=letters[1:3])

ui <- fluidPage(
  HTML(htmlTable(table(df$a,df$b)))
)

server <- function(input,output, session)
{
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```